# Failed to load font in SFML C++ on other computers

Tags: c++, sfml

I am making an SFML project using Visual Studio, and I have an error when sharing it with other people (works fine on my computer).
Basically they get the error

> Failed to load font "../fonts/BalooPaaji2.ttf" (failed to create the font face)

So I tried to uninstall the font in my OS fonts and only keep it in the project itself, and everything still works fine for me.

I though it was maybe a directory problem but if so why would the .exe file work fine for me and not other people ?

Here is the code of my write function:

```
void write(sf::RenderWindow& window, std::string t1, sf::IntRect rect) {
    //load font
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("../fonts/BalooPaaji2.ttf");

    //create the text element
    sf::Text text(t1, font);
    text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
    text.setFillColor(sf::Color(0,0,0,150));

    //size and place the text element according to the space available, this is specific of my project (and probably could be optimized) so you can skip this part
    text.setCharacterSize(rect.height/2);
    sf::FloatRect textRect = text.getLocalBounds();
    text.setOrigin(textRect.left + textRect.width / 2.0f, textRect.top + textRect.height / 2.0f);

    text.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(rect.left + rect.width/2, rect.top + rect.height / 2));
    if (t1 == "Play") {
        text.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(rect.left + rect.width / 2, rect.top + rect.height / 1.8));
    }

    window.draw(text);
}
```

My structure looks like that:

[image: Project structure]

I don't have any clues of where this problem could come from, any help will be appreciated and feel free to ask for more information you could need.

Comment: @drescherjm Well it should be since they have the exact same folder containing everything on the screenshot, and I'm calling "../fonts/BalooPaaji2.ttf" from the ".exe" which works perfectly fine on my computer (I can run the .exe too)

Comment: How do you execute your programme? From the `.exe` or from visual studio? Where is the `.sln` file?

Comment: @DipStax I execute it from the .exe file, but it also works from Visual Studio. The .sln file is in the same level that the folders we see in the screenshot